# Understanding atomic transactions in Django

Tags: python, django, transactions, atomic

I'm trying to update two IntegerField's in django 1.8.4 so I've decided to use atomic transactions, but I have some doubts:

1- Is that good idea to use atomic transactions in this case? What is the real benefit of using it? How much more efficient is it?

2- How can I check if these two pieces work same as each other or not?

A.

```
@transaction.atomic
class LinkManager(models.Manager):
    def vote_up(self, pk, increment=True):
        if increment:
            <update field 1, incrementing by 1>
        else:
            <update field 1, decrementing by 1>
```

B.

```
 class LinkManager(models.Manager):
        def vote_up(self, pk, increment=True):
            if increment:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    <update field 1, incrementing by 1>
            else:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    <update field 1, decrementing by 1>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Is it a good idea to use atomic transactions in this case?**

No, the `atomic` decorator makes sure that either all or no updates will be executed in the transactions. It's probably completely useless in this case.

**What's the benefit of `atomic`?**

Assuming you're updating a few models from a form, the `atomic` decorator will ensure that either all models get updated, or if there's an error. None at all.

**Is it more efficient?**

No, absolutely not. It's a data safety thing, it's actually less efficient and slower than a regular update as it needs to create a transaction for every block.

**How can it work?**

Update within the database, instead of fetching the result and writing it back just let the database increment it for you.

Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import F
SomeModel.objects.filter(pk=123).update(some_field=F('some_field') + 1)
```